# Torch's loss.backward() hanged on ParlAI

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation, parlai

I am interested in [Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08895) and [Movie Dialog QA](http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/babi/movie_dialog_dataset.tgz). Recently facebook announced AI training framework called ParlAI, which supports many models and datasets. Although I tried below command on ParlAI, the training stopped at first `loss.backward()` at `memnn.py`. I waited almost one day, but `loss.backward()` didn't finish. I have checked this by printing debug and `[Using Cuda]` printing. Actually my GPU was working because it used some memory. I checked this by `nvidia-smi -l 1`.

```
python examples/train_model.py -m memnn -t "#moviedd-qa" -bs 32 --gpu 0 -e 10
```

Then, I switched to simple task, and it finished a few minutes.

```
python examples/train_model.py -m memnn -t "babi:task1k:1" -bs 32 --gpu 0 -e 10
```

I realize `#moviedd-qa` is more complicated compared to [babi](https://research.fb.com/downloads/babi/) task. But how long does it usually take to train this model in my setting? Does anyone try to train this model via ParlAI? I am afraid this is not bug of ParlAI. Could you advise me to proceed my work?

**My Environment**

- Ubunt 16.04.03 LTS, 64 bit
- python 3.6.1 (Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit))
- GPU: GTX 1080 ti
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
- torch.**version**: '0.2.0_3'

I am also [asking developers at ParlAI at their github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI/issues/307), but no responses.